# local app using ngrok having issue with http tunnel but not with tcp tunnel

Tags: ngrok, http-tunneling

I have an app that runs on my localhost port:3000. I am using ngrok to get a public URL. Now when i am using a tcp tunnel as below:
./ngrok tcp 3000

i get the public url as below:
tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:14964 -> localhost:3000

I try sending REST post req to https://0.tcp.ngrok.io:14964/ and it works.

But when i try to use an HTTP channel.
./ngrok http --bind-tls "both" -host-header=localhost 3000

i get public URL:
"https://b9076b83.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000"

Now when i try to send the post request to https://b9076b83.ngrok.io/, it doesn't work, i get a 502 error.

What really could be the issue?